# High solr server load on slave due to delayed replication

Tags: performance, search, solr, lucene, replication

I am currently working with `Java-1.7`, `Solr-4.8.1` with `tomcat 7`. The solr configuration has master & slave ( 2 Slaves) architecture.

Master & Slave 2 are in same server location (say zone A) , whereas Slave 1 is in another server in different zone (say zone B). There is latency of 40 ms between two zones.

Now, a days we are facing high load on Slave 1 & we suspect that it is due to delay in data replication from Master server. These days we are finding these below mentioned replication information in log files, but such lines are not in previous files on the Slave 1 server. Also, such information is not there in any Slave 2 log files (might be due to same zone of master & slave 2).

```
  INFO: [Core] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={wt=json&command=details&_=1441708786003} status=0 QTime=173 
  INFO: [Core] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={wt=json&command=details&_=1441708787976} status=0 QTime=1807 
  INFO: [Core] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={wt=json&command=details&_=1441708791563} status=0 QTime=7140 
  INFO: [Core] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={wt=json&command=details&_=1441708800450} status=0 QTime=1679
```

Please confirm if we our thought that increased replication time (which can be due to servers connectivity issues) is the reason for high load on solr.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect that delayed replication would cause Solr load -- since nothing has changed from the current searchers standpoint then queries can be just as fast. Solr is not going to perform extra work to complete searches if there is an incomplete replication.